# Getting error if response is with 500 return

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have my node js response return code as below. It works fine when the return value is success. And if the return value is not found, i get statusErrorCode as 500 which is throwing error as unhandled error status.

**Node JS CODE**

```
 request(options).then(function(data){
      resp.json(JSON.parse(data))
 }).catch(function(data){
    resp.json(JSON.parse(data))
  })
```

**possibly unhandled status error code 500**

I am newbie to node js and i am using angularjs in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to parse the error as JSON when it probably isn't. Try this and then check your console to see what kind of an error object you have and determine how to best handle it:

```
request(options).then(function(data){
    resp.json(JSON.parse(data))
}).catch(function(e){
    console.warn( e );
});
```

Comment: This is my response taken from inspect element/network <html><body><b>Http/1.1 Service Unavailable</b></body> </html> and the status code is 503: service unavailable